# Have a JSON_PARSER_ERROR after sent a JSON representation of a parameter of a REST service

Tags: webservices, rest

I have a custom REST service which has a get and post methods. Both, get and post methods use the same wrapped object. In get case it returns this wrapped object, in post - I was hoping to have the same wrapped as input parameter for POST method, but I'm having this error

> [
>       {
>           "errorCode": "JSON_PARSER_ERROR",
>           "message": "Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization: name at [line:2, column:18]"
>       } ]

Input JSON

```
{        
        "name": "XX 1142"
    }
```

and wrapped is

```
global class BlahblahService {
 ...
    global class Wrapper {
        global String id { get; set; }
        global String name { get; set; }
    global Wrapper() {}
    }
}
```

If I do this in Execute Anonymous everything deserializes fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the signature of your POST method is this:

```
@HttpPost
global static void doPost(Wrapper xyz) {
    ...
}
```

then the deserialization expects an extra object layer corresponding to the method signature (including using the method argument names). This is a convenience for cases where there are just a few values being passed in that a class is not needed, but gets in the way when you are using a class to model the data passed.

So you would need this JSON:

```
{
    "xyz": {        
        "name": "XX 1142"
    }
}
```

In cases like this, it is probably better to explicitly JSON.deserialize directly from the RestRequest into a Wrapper object so you are fully in control of the process and can have the desired JSON format and re-use the Wrapper class internally.

**PS** This is well covered in this answered question [Apex REST Web Service: Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15259/apex-rest-web-service-unexpected-parameter-encountered-during-deserialization).